# retained sizes in the hashtable and it's mutex

Tags: java, memory, hashtable, mutex

I have used the YourKit profiler and am I trying to analyse why this hashtable and it's mutex are retaining up to 196 KB ; [image: The] image is attached here.
Yes this is a problem since I have about 2000 objects retaining 196 kb of data; which is a potential problem. 
This is a thread safe env; hence a hashtable is used instead of anything else.

Comment: Why do you just don't go deeper to see what elements get this size?

Comment: @egorlitvinenko within the mutex there is a table contained which ocntributes to about 80% of the space occupied by the complete hashtable. If I ConcurrentHashMap or any other data structure would the retained size reduce?

Comment: also the size mentioned is 137 where as only 15 elements are present in the hashtable why so?

Comment: @bhavs you need to go down the object graph following the largest retained size, so in your example drill into **mutex** and keep going until the **shallow size** gets to substantial values - this is your offender.

Comment: @diginoise Do you see that mutex is Hashtable instance itself?

Comment: @egorlitvinenko I did see that... `this` is passed as **mutex** when you call `Hashtable.keySet()` which  returns `new SynchronisedSet()`. I do appreciate that 'drilling' into **mutex** will get you back to the offending Hashtable. I was only explaining in general how to find, where the retained memory is coming from.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> If I ConcurrentHashMap or any other data structure would the retained size reduce?

The best way to reduce capacity it is set initial capacity explicitly (it is parameter of constructor).

Generally, it is better to use ConcurrentHashMap, because it uses stripped technique and more performant then Hashtable.

mutex is yours Hashtable instance in that case. That is why you see this occupied size, because you see one object twice.

Hashtable (as many other hashmap, etc.) has dynamic size. Hashtable.size - is real size of reserved internal hash table, unlike Hashtable.count, which is count of elements.

The only place, where bigger size part occupied is Hashtable itself, so go inside Hashtable.table and you will see, what is it.